# Why is there a phenyl shift in this reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, rearrangements

Why is there a phenyl shift in this reaction. I believe that the +R effect by 2 phenyl groups would be better than the +R effect by oxygen because of its lone pair. Can somebody please confirm?
[image]

Comment: There's no methyl shift but a phenyl shift. What else would you do besides shifting the carbocation and forming a ketone?

Comment: If a reaction is taken from higher stability to lower stability,IMO the rxn shouldn't carry out.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar Can this be explained by the octet rule that a complete octet of all the atoms will be more stable than the resonance by +R effect?

Comment: @Ritviz Yes, the carbocation can complete it's octet if it gets a back bond from the oxygen next to it and this is what someone meant when they mentioned that ketone formation is the driving force of the reaction, in the comments of your previous question.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar Thanks for the clarification